# Trouble logging data from multiple instances to separate log files

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender, log4net-configuration

In my usual logging experiences, I merely create an `ILog` instance in each class by using something like `mylog = LogManager.GetLogger( name)`, which gives me a unique Logger per instance.  Everything logs to the same file and works great.

However, now I've got a situation where I want to log to two separate files.  I accomplish this with the following logging.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO"/>
      <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/>
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss.fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="File" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss.fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="File" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

and in code behind, I set the name of the `FileAppender` on a per-instance basis by giving it a unique name:

`log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = unique_path_here;`

If I instantiate one object called "test1", the "test1.log" file is created.  When I instantiate another object called "test2", the "test2.log" file is created.  Everything seems like it's working great, until I start to call methods in each object.  When I alternate calls, data for one object gets written to the other object's file at first, but then data gets logged to the correct file.  For example, here's a simplified example of what happens:

1. test1.log() -> writes to test1.log
2. test2.log() -> writes to test2.log
3. test1.log() -> writes a line to test2.log, then the rest is written to test1.log
4. test2.log() -> writes a lint to test1.log, then the rest is written to test2.log

If I run the two methods in parallel, all lines get written to one file or the other.  Then what's really weird is that the other, mostly-used file is *never* written to again!

I'm not sure where to look next.  If I've created a Logger instance via GetLogger and passed it a unique name, and this a private member variable, how is it possible that it starts to write to the wrong file?

Answer (score 0):

Sure seems pretty obvious now that "GlobalContext" is suspicious for a class name.  :)  I will look into this to see if the problem is that the property is shared across all Logger instances, and if so, whether or not there's another way to set the log name for a particular log instance.

EDIT -- well, that wasn't it.  I replaced the property in logging.xml with `<File value="TEMP" />` and then in code behind, I loaded the `FileAppender` and set its `File` property to the correct path.  The behavior is identical.  :(

EDIT -- The solution is to create a `FileAppender` per instance, rather than a `Logger` per instance.  I'm not sure why it took so long for me to come to that conclusion, but I eventually did and now it looks like it's working.